# How to store complex meta data using Asana's external data feature

Tags: python, api, asana

**Background**

My organization uses the Asana platform to coordinate our work efforts. I have been leveraging Asana's API to automate a number of our daily operations and as well integrate Asana's platform with other external services we use. I interact with Asana's API using python and the requests library to make GET, POST, and PUT requests.

Often times I need to GET or POST to a specific task within Asana, I can often achieve this using Asana's auto-generated task ID.

```
result = requests.get("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/task_id", headers)
```

However there are times where it is useful for me to be able to identify a task by specific information stored within it. I have been able to successfully do so by storing the specific information in question within task's meta data, referred to as "external data" by Asana.

```
result = requests.get("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/external_id", headers)
```

Both of these methods have served me well. However I am having trouble storing specific data within a task's external data which I outline in the section below.

**Problem**

Currently when I store meta data in a task external data my PUT/POST request is as follows:

```
header = {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer " + AUTH_TOKEN
}

data = {
    "data" : {
        "name" : "Burgers",
        "external" : {
            "id" : "external_id",
            "data" : "data_value"
        }
    }
}

url = "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/task_id"
result = requests.put(url, headers=header, json=data)
return result
```

The important thing to note here is that the "data_value" is a single string. However according to Asana's documentation [here](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/custom-external-data) the "data_value" can actually store a dictionary of keys and values. I have attempted to pass a dictionary object by doing the following:

```
data = {
    "data" : {
        "name" : "Burgers",
        "external" : {
            "id" : "external_id",
            "data" : {
               "data_value" : "some_data", 
               "data_value_2" : "some_data"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I continue to receive an error stating:

> "{"errors":[{"message":"external: data: Value is not a string: [object Object]","help":"For more information on API status codes and how to handle them, read the docs on errors: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors"}]}"

Any ideas where I am going wrong? Has anyone had success with this?